# How to change the image to the size of the picture box?

Tags: c#, image

As the title says I can't see why the image isn't changing size. Can anyone see?

```
{
            OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
            dlg.Title = "Open bitmap or jpeg.";
            //dlg.Filter = "jpg files (*.jpg);*.jpg;*.* | bmp files (*.bmp); *.bmp";
            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                this.pictureBoxMap1.Image = new Bitmap(dlg.OpenFile());
                Image newImage = this.pictureBoxMap1.Image;
                pictureBoxMap1.Height = newImage.Height;
                pictureBoxMap1.Width = newImage.Width;
            }
            dlg.Dispose();
```

Comment: What is the `SizeMode` property currently set to?

Comment: Oh yes your right.. it needs to be the other way round ^^

Comment: Apparently that can't be done as the file is readonly..

Comment: Do you want to change image size or picture box size?

Comment: Aren't you first setting newImage from the PictureBox and then setting the Height and Width of the PictureBox to the sizes of newImage - that were set from the same PictureBox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        OpenFileDialog fd = new OpenFileDialog();
        DialogResult r = fd.ShowDialog();
        if (r == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pictureBoxMap1.Image = Bitmap.FromFile(fd.FileName);
            pictureBoxMap1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            pictureBoxMap1.Refresh();
       }
```

Try this.

Comment: This does not do anything, the image still does not fit the picture box